# Tracking and comparing Skeletons with pre-defined Skeleton

Tags: windows, kinect, xbox360

I'm currently working on a project for school that requires me to create a certain piece of software with the Kinect hardware. The software is closely related to an aerobics/exercise "game".

However, being that I have never worked for the Kinect, I'm somewhat clueless as to where to start. I have downloaded the SDK and the Toolkit browser, as well as some (unofficial?) Toolkit.

I have some experience in Java programming, but no knowledge whatsoever how to work with C/C++/C# nor Visual Studio.

I'm basically looking for tutorials that could help me get more knowledgeable with the Kinect and how programming for it works. I tried looking for a few but they were either outdated or really confusing that I couldn't keep up with them.

My main goal in the project is to figure out how I can see when a live skeleton holds both his arms above his head and when they're next to his body (A jumping jack exercise).

Can anyone help me along the right direction with a few links or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is not too conceptually different from Java.  Microsoft even has online help on the subject: [The C# Programming Language for Java Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms228602%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Though I'd suggest finding a good book that doesn't wrap C# in the context of another language -- learn C#, not "C# as it relates to Java."

Learning Kinect development should be done through the Toolkit examples.  There is really no better way.  **BEWARE** online tutorials!  Many were written for older versions of the SDK that are no longer compatible.  Anything written for SDK < 1.5 will just not work, without effort to port it.

Detecting a jumping-jack could be done through gesture recognition.  There are a few libraries out there that provide this for the official Microsoft Kinect SDK -- the two I generally point to are [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) and the [Fizbin Gesture Library](https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures).  Both provide gesture recognition, just using different methods.

In the case of the Fizbin Gesture Library you declare a series of classes that define how a gesture is constructed.  For example, here is how the library define swiping the left hand towards the right of the body:

```
namespace Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures.Segments
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first part of the swipe right gesture
    /// </summary>
    public class SwipeRightSegment1 : IRelativeGestureSegment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the gesture.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="skeleton">The skeleton.</param>
        /// <returns>GesturePartResult based on if the gesture part has been completed</returns>
        public GesturePartResult CheckGesture(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            // left hand in front of left Shoulder
            if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
            {
                // left hand below shoulder height but above hip height
                if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
                {
                    // left hand left of left Shoulder
                    if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.X)
                    {
                        return GesturePartResult.Succeed;
                    }

                    return GesturePartResult.Pausing;
                }

                return GesturePartResult.Fail;
            }

            return GesturePartResult.Fail;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The second part of the swipe right gesture
    /// </summary>
    public class SwipeRightSegment2 : IRelativeGestureSegment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the gesture.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="skeleton">The skeleton.</param>
        /// <returns>GesturePartResult based on if the gesture part has been completed</returns>
        public GesturePartResult CheckGesture(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            // left hand in front of left Shoulder
            if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
            {
                // left hand below shoulder height but above hip height
                if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
                {
                    // left hand left of left Shoulder
                    if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X > skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.X)
                    {
                        return GesturePartResult.Succeed;
                    }

                    return GesturePartResult.Pausing;
                }

                return GesturePartResult.Fail;
            }

            return GesturePartResult.Fail;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The third part of the swipe right gesture
    /// </summary>
    public class SwipeRightSegment3 : IRelativeGestureSegment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the gesture.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="skeleton">The skeleton.</param>
        /// <returns>GesturePartResult based on if the gesture part has been completed</returns>
        public GesturePartResult CheckGesture(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            // //left hand in front of left Shoulder
            if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z < skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
            {
                // left hand below shoulder height but above hip height
                if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y < skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y > skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].Position.Y)
                {
                    // left hand left of left Shoulder
                    if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X > skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X)
                    {
                        return GesturePartResult.Succeed;
                    }

                    return GesturePartResult.Pausing;
                }

                return GesturePartResult.Fail;
            }

            return GesturePartResult.Fail;
        }
    }
}
```

You can follow the comments in the code to see how the hand is moving across the body.

In the case of your jumping-jack, you can define the hands relative to a series of joints on the way up and then on the way down.  If I were to quickly spit out a series of checks they would be:

1. Left/Right Hand below Hip Center
2. Left/Right Hand above Hip Center & Left/Right Hand outside Left/Right Elbow
3. Left/Right Hand above Spine & Left/Right Hand outside Left/Right Elbow
4. Left/Right Hand above Left/Right Shoulder & Left/Right Hand outside Left/Right Elbow
5. Left/Right Hand above Head

... if all those match, you have half a jumping-jack.  Do all the checks in reverse under the same `Gesture` and you have a full upper-body jumping-jack.  You can add in leg positions to get a full-body jumping-jack.

The Kinect Toolbox could also be used to define the gesture.  I've just not used it personally, so I can't speak to the steps involved.